# Choice of decimal figures after putting parentheses

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, format

I am trying to add parentheses to numbers in Excel 2016. Since I do not necessarily need them in the same column where the figures are, I used the formula `="("&cell&")"`.

The problem is that, in this way, I am no longer able to decide how many decimal figures to keep. Even though I selected three decimal figures, after implementing the formula, the figures become all the available.

EDIT: figure

[image]

I tried to work with custom formats but I am stuck. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example and maybe an image of what you have and what you want?  This would help us understand what EXACTLY is going on and what you want.

Comment: @Dale Figure added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FIXED()` to achieve this:

Value in `A1` - `15,0236598`
Formula in `B1` - `="("&FIXED(A1;3;FALSE)&")"`

Just change the `3` in the formula to the number of decimal places you need.

[image: Screenshot]

Note that my version of Excel is formatted for Norway, hence the use of a `,` as the decimal separator and a `;` in the formula. You will need to fix this for your version of Excel.

Comment: It works. No need to change anything in the formula depending on the decimal separator. Thanks

Comment: Good :) The note about changing the decimal separator is important as others may have the same question but be using an English formatted version of Excel which uses a . decimal separator and a , in the formula :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Kevin's answer, if you don't want to use a formula, is to use a **custom number format**. I see many advantages over a formula:

- Custom number format is a format, which means you can apply it and paste it anywhere, without the need to rewrite a formula
- It doesn't convert your number into a text, like Kevin's formula does, which means you can still apply mathematical functions, e.g. `SUM()`
- You don't need a second cell
- You don't need to update the formula manually, should you need more or less decimals. Just use Excel's buttons to quickly add or remove decimals (see below).

---

**To apply this format**, follow these steps:

1. Right click on the cell you want to format, and click `Format Cells...`
2. In the Format window, select the `Number` tab
3. Select the `Custom` category
4. In the text input, write the following code: `(0.0);-(0.0);(0.0);@`
5. Click `OK`

[image]

---

To add or remove decimals, simply use the following buttons, like you would do with classic number or currency formats:

[image]

---

### Explanation of the format

```
(0.0);-(0.0);(0.0);@
```

The format has 4 properties, separated by a `;`, which apply to 4 types of content, in this order:

1. Format applied to positive numbers
2. Format applied to negative numbers (notice the `-`, which you can also move inside the parenthesis)
3. Format applied to null numbers
4. Format applied to text

This allows you to customize how numbers are displayed, based on their sign. For instance, you could color the negative numbers in red, or display a `-` if the number equals zero.

The `0.0` is a placeholder, and basically mean "a number with one decimal, separated with a dot". You could also write "0|000", which would translate as "a number with 3 decimals, separated with a bar".

The parenthesis are just text. If you wanted your number to be between `A` and `Z`, you could write:

```
"A"0.0"Z";-"A"0.0"Z";"A"0.0"Z";@
```

Note that some characters, like letters, need to be enclosed between two `"`, which basically displays "as is" what's in between.

For more information about these format, which are really a useful thing to master, here are some useful links:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4
- https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-custom-number-formats-excel/
- https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats